# How to produce a 303 Http Response in Django?

Tags: python, django, http, rest

Last couple of days we were discussing at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401191/how-to-return-random-items-restfully) the best to manage randomness in a RESTful way; today I went to play a little bit with some ideas in Django only to find that there is no easy standard way of returning a 303 response (nor a 300 one, btw), that is, there doesn't seem to exist an HttpResponseSeeOther inside django.HTTP or in another place.

Do you know any means for achieving this?

Comment: Just for information: a proposition to add a `HttpResponseSeeOther` was closed with a wontfix in 2011. Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13277

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could just override HttpResponse, like the other Responses do:

```
class HttpResponseSeeOther(HttpResponseRedirect):
    status_code = 303

return HttpResponseSeeOther('/other-url/')
```

Comment: You could also file this as a ticket with a patch.

Answer (score 21):

The generic HttpResponse object lets you specify any status code you want:

```
response = HttpResponse(content="", status=303)
response["Location"] = "http://example.com/redirect/here/"
```

If you need something re-usable then Gerald's answer is definitely valid; simply create your own HttpResponseSeeOther class. Django only provides these specific classes for a few of the most common status codes.