# How can I return HTTP status code 204 from a Django view?

Tags: django

I want to return status code `204 No Content` from a Django view. It is in response to an automatic POST which updates a database and I just need to indicate the update was successful (without redirecting the client).

There are subclasses of `HttpResponse` to handle most other codes but not 204.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I haven't done this before, but have you tried setting the status attribute of the response object before returning the response from your view? Also, here is another SO question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408541/how-to-produce-a-303-http-response-in-django

Answer (score 214, accepted):

```
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: Thanks. W3C states "The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body" so (assuming the content parameter maps to the message body) it should be blank though, right?

Comment: For anyone reading who isn't just concerned with a 204 code you can use a message body with Django's HTTPResponse methods.

Comment: More here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#returning-errors

Comment: And instead of using magic numbers, django also provides constants (see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/), e.g. `return HttpResponse(status=rest_framework.status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)`

Comment: @nietonfir Python has built-in module for this `from http import HTTPStatus; return HttpResponse(status=HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT)`

Answer (score 30):

When using [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), there is a `status` keyword argument.

```
return render(request, 'template.html', status=204)
```

(Note that in the case of status 204 there shouldn't be a response body, but this method is useful for other status codes.)

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a redirect though?

Comment: No redirect needed, it should do the same as the top answer, just shorter syntax. (Using status code 204 for a redirect would be very weird, if it works at all).

Comment: Oh.. Is there a way I could pass an error status without actually reloading the page or redirecting to new page? I want to use it when a file that user is trying to save already exists. I tried 409 & 422. But, they redirect it to new page. I know AJAX is the other solution. But was wondering if Django had any trick.

Comment: Status codes are used when visitors are loading a page. So they have to be already loading a page; changing the code doesn't cause an extra redirect but you're still loading a new page. If they're on a page and you want to inform them without reloading, then I don't think there's a way to update the code of the current page (I don't think it would be terribly useful anyway). So: if they save a form which sends them to a new page, then you can choose any status code for the result page. If it doesn't load a new page, just show message and forget status code.

Comment: I get what you're saying. But, I really need to do just update the page. So, I guess, I'll have to use AJAX + Django :( Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Well ajax is a good way for that, but then you're just changing the ajax request status code, not the main page.

Answer (score 23):

Either what Steve Mayne answered, or build your own by subclassing HttpResponse:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HttpResponseNoContent(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 204

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponseNoContent()
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers work mostly, but they do not produce a fully compliant HTTP 204 responses, because they still contain a content header. This can result in WSGI warnings and is picked up by test tools like Django Web Test.

Here is an improved class for a HTTP 204 response that is compliant. (based on this [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16632)):

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HttpResponseNoContent(HttpResponse):
    """Special HTTP response with no content, just headers.

    The content operations are ignored.
    """

    def __init__(self, content="", mimetype=None, status=None, content_type=None):
        super().__init__(status=204)

        if "content-type" in self.headers:
            del self.headers["content-type"]

    def _set_content(self, value):
        pass

    def _get_content(self, value):
        pass

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponseNoContent()
```