# How to be HTTP (cache) friendly on an index page that presents random content?

Tags: http, rest, caching, http-headers, http-caching

Let's say I have a quoting site, that accepts new quotes and presents a random one every time you visit it.

I would have resources like:

```
|        URL            | Method |     What is does     |
|-----------------------|--------|----------------------|
| /                     | GET    | Shows a random quote |
| /quote                | POST   | Create a new quote   |
| /quote/slang-of-quote | GET    | Presents a quote     |
```

Resources could be presented on HTML, JSON, XML, image/png, etc.

Proper headers for cache control would be sent on relevant resources (probably just on `/quote/another-quote` URLs).

What is the beast approach (for the index page to give a user a random quote) other than issuing a 307 to a real quote resource? Is that even nice to HTTP/REST?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return random items RESTfully?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401191/how-to-return-random-items-restfully)